# Connecting odoo with zk device

Tags: python, odoo-8

I am trying to connect odoo with zk device (ZKTeco model K40).I installed zklib to download attendance info from the device.
I tried the following code:

```
import sys
import time
import zklib
from zklib 
import zkconst
zk = zklib.ZKLib("192.168.1.201", 4370)
conn=zk.connect()
```

When I print conn, its value is False, even when I am sure that the connection parameters are well. I tried pyzk library too, but I had the same connection problem. Then, I tried to connect with another zksoftware (ZKTime) and it connected. 
What else can I do to connect odoo 8 with zk device?

Comment: Can you give me please more details about how did you use the zkemkeeper with odoo?

Comment: @Borealis I access to the dll with: pythoncom.CoInitialize()
zk = win32com.client.Dispatch('zkemkeeper.ZKEM.1') and then I used the methods I needed. Example: zk.Connect_Net(ip, port). I hope this help you

Comment: thanks for your answer is really kind from you. Can you please tell me if you did access to dll in windows or ubuntu. In short I will be thankful if you have time to give me more details because I still have problem with it

Comment: @Borealis I accessed to dll in windows. First I registered it and then I put that code in python. What problem do you have exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve this problem using the zkemkeeper.dll and its methods. The modules didn't work due to the device model (I am using ZK40)

Comment: In one of the devices at my client's place, there is a pin enabled for the device. How can I use this to connect to the device? I tried with just ip and port but it doesn't seem to be working. And is there any way to disable the pin of a zk device?

Comment: If the device has a pin configured you must use 3 parameters to communicate with it: ip, port and pin. It is possible to remove the pin directly from the device configuration.

Comment: zk = ZK('ip', port=4370, timeout=5, pin='12345'), is this what you're talking about?

Comment: The library doesn't seem to be supporting a pin. And isn't removing the pin from the device a security risk?

Comment: @YaseenShareef You're right, the connection method of the library does not support pin as a parameter. To do this, you must set the pin as the communication pin of the server through the `SetCommPassword (pin_parameter)` method. After setting the server communication pin you should be able to connect normally with `Connect_Net (ip, port)`. I hope it works for you. I do **not** advise you to remove the security pin from the device because it is certainly a risk.

Answer (score 0):

Python **ZKLib** is not maintained and unstable (for now), it is better to use **[pyzk](https://github.com/fananimi/pyzk)** it is better built, more stable and easier to use with somewhat of a [**documentation**](https://pyzk.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
pip install pyzk
```